# Cannot obfuscate dll

Tags: c#, obfuscation, confuserex

I'm using Confuserex for obfuscate a `dll`, I compiled it using visual studio, then I opened ConfuserEx GUI, dropped the `dll` on the project tab, and then in the settings tab I added a new rule with the maximum preset.

After that, I click on "Protect" button available on the protect tab, and when I open the "obfuscated" `dll` with dotpeek a disassmbler software provided by intellij I can read all the method and class as the `dll` is never obfuscated.

This does not happen with `.exe` only with `dll`, what I'm doing wrong?

**UPDATE**

example structure:

```
namespace Test
{
    public class Foo<T> : ViewModel
    {

        public Example() { }
    }
}
```

Comment: Every single method remains unaltered?  Are they all public methods?

Comment: @Plutonix yes, check my update for an example

Comment: Think for a moment.  If `Example` got changed to `aai()` how well would it work with the app that calls it?  Please read [ask] and take the [tour]

Comment: @Plutonix okay, so you have implicited suggested to me to use the Packer? I used it in the past and performance of the app is slow when I start the application, that's why I want obfuscate the dll without include it in the exe

Answer (score 0):

From the answer from this Issue.
https://github.com/yck1509/ConfuserEx/issues/573

n-dimens answer :
"it is because the dll and pdb in the same folder. In this case, dotPeek opens the source code instead of the decompiled"

You can just rename or remove the file .pdb file. Then in dotPeek can not decompile it.